# 32 bit sharepoint designer 2010 will work with sharepoint server 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

My question is whether 32 bit SharePoint Designer 2010 will work with SharePoint Server 2010 or not. SharePoint Server 2010 is 64 bit only while SharePoint Designer is available in 32 bit or 64 bit.  Which one is best to work with SharePoint Server 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, it will work. I think your choice will depend on what version of MS Office is already installed. My understanding is that they should match. So if you have 32-bit MS office, install 32-bit SPD otherwise 64-bit.

Comment: yes, I download 64bit sharepoint designer 2010 and it gives me error that first uninstall office 2007 and then install spdesigner 2010.

Comment: Refer to http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16573. " If you elect to install both applications side-by-side, you must download the 32-bit version of SharePoint Designer 2010, and install it after installing SharePoint Designer 2007."

Comment: thanks for replying. I have one more question. In central admin, The option of create new web application is disabled. When i go to create a new site collection there is also an option of creating a new web application when I try to create it it gives me error Acess is denied. Sign in with an other account.. I am login through administrator account still this error comes. Any solution ?

Comment: Run internet explorer as administrator and try again... Assuming you are farm admin.

Comment: check it, still problem

Answer (score 2):

The simple fact that you can download a 32-bit version of designer tells me that it should work with SharePoint Server 2010.

As regards which version would work "best", I would follow Ashish's advice around currently installed products.

EDIT:

From the Microsoft [download site](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16573) for Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2010 (32-bit):

"This is the 32-bit edition of SharePoint Designer 2010. It is the recommended configuration for most users."

Comment: thanks for replying. I have one more question. In central admin, The option of create new web application is disabled. When i go to create a new site collection there is also an option of creating a new web application when I try to create it it gives me error Acess is denied. Sign in with an other account.. I am login through administrator account still this error comes. Any solution ?

Comment: You need to be a local server administrator, as well as a SharePoint farm administrator to create Web apps.

Comment: what do you mean by local server administrator ? I'm using sharepoint on my laptop